# batch File -How to check if path to a bin folder is set

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I my batch file i want to check if path to the following location is set

```
 C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin
```

in any of the variable either in system variable or user defined variable

my need is to use content of the bin folder ; what if the user has not installed the way quoted above but has done something like

```
C:\WindowsinstallerXML\bin
```

or
     D:\WindowsInstaller\bin

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check every defined variable for the string, this would be the way.  If you want to specifically check the path variable replacing `set` with `echo %path%` would work too.

```
set | find "C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin" > NUL 2>&1 || goto badinstall
```

If you want to check the install directory, I suggest checking to see if there is a registry value for it, if there is you can pull it like this.

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=    " %%a in ('reg query \HKCU\path\to\subkey\here /v "keyhere" ^| findstr /C:"keyhere"') do set wixmlpath=%%a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
PATH="C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin";%PATH%
```

Basically, instead of checking if it is set, why not to set explicitly in your script ?

Comment: suppose i am taking this batch file to another computer and on that pc the path to bin looks like as specified above then

Comment: like d:\wixinstalldir\bin then

Comment: So, basically that path can be anything. I suggest instead of doing reverse lookup on environment variable you take that path as a command line argument. Let the user of your script decide what path to specify.

Comment: can u cite the code for it must be like when the batch file is run user is asked to set path to the bin folder something like that

Comment: just replied with sample script, see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set input=%1
IF DEFINED input (ECHO you entered %input%) ELSE (ECHO usage: script bin_file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of one of the binary files, then you can use a FOR variable `~PATH:` modifier to check if the path to that binary is currently in your PATH. And it will give you the actual path :)

```
for %F in (someFile.exe) do @if "%~$path:F" neq "" echo %~$path:F
```

If you want to use the code in a batch file, then each `%` must be doubled as `%%`.